# Center element above scroll container in container with padding

Tags: html, css

I have got this HTML:

```
<div class="A">
  <div class="B1">
    <div class="C1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="B2"></div>
</div>
```

.A is a container with padding, B1 contains a long list and scrolls. .B2 should be aligned in the list (vertically and horizontally centered like a loading image).

How do I achieve that? The horizontal alignment is not working for me:
https://jsfiddle.net/1phyb6y8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it is not working: the absolute positioned element does not ignore the padding of its parent. I've added a div `.inner` with `position: relative` and put both, `.B2` (loading animation) and `.B1` (container with scrollbar) in it. This way `.B2`'s position is calculated based on the width of `.inner` which has no padding.

```
<div class="A">
  <div class="inner"> /* .inner { position: relative; } */
    <div class="B2">
    </div>
    <div class="B1">
      <div class="C1">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[See the updated JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/1phyb6y8/3/)

Comment: The green dot should not vanish when scrolling :)

Comment: I've updated the answer but someone deleted my comment, so I don't know if you saw my update. If it solved your problem, I would be also thankful if you would accept my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I added a container to your structure so the .B1 and .B2 divs are in it.
B1-container takes a `relative` position. B2, as you did takes an `absolute` position and proper positionning to be at the center (I added `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` so the div in the center stays in the center whatever happens to the block width).
So B2 will always be centered above B1 and move independently from it.
Hope it will help !

```
<div class="A">
    <div class="B1-container">
        <div class="B2"></div>
        <div class="B1">
            <div class="C1"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[See on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xot3py37/)